# How to remove Database fields from Crystal report programmatically

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a Crystal report and i set database fields manually (there are

multiple tables). What i want to do is to remove some database fields

programmatically when there is no data returned from my query.

Comment: You can do that in the report itself.

Comment: How to do this programmaticaty?? i mean if the query don't returns rows how to remove some database fields programmatically??

Comment: why do it programmatically if there is support to do this right in the report itself.

Comment: But if the query returns rows  the report should display these rows

Comment: you don't know how to do it in crystal reports ?

Comment: Yes please explain it to me

Comment: Thanks but this supress all fields in the section and there is fields in this section that i need to keep them

Comment: you can format individual fields too.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497072/Suppress-field-in-Crystal-Reports